# Store form data into hidden field using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, json, hidden-field

I have a form that has a popup page with another form. In that popup form I want to take all fields filled out and store it in a single field in the main parent form via a hidden field. So that when the parent form gets submitted I can get all the fields via the hidden fields via php. How could I do that with jquery? Can I take all the fields from the popup form and store it as a json string in the hidden field? Then in php be able to turn that jquery string into an object so I can get easy access to all the form values? If so then how would I take all the fields from the popup form and turn it into a json string? Or is there a better/easier way?

Comment: It might be a better idea to simply wrap some of the form elements in a div that is used as the modal(?) popup form, this way the data is really inside the form but it looks as though it is a popup.

Comment: @Dale Sorry that is what I am doing actually. Using the modal from the jquery UI I just wrap the form in a hidden div and call the dialog action. But still though how would I store the form data into a hidden variable on the parent form where I can easily get all the data from php once the form is submitted? It doesnt have to be json, but thought that would be the easiest.

Comment: MetalFrog has read my mind with this one +1 for you sir

Comment: Hrm, seems that I've misunderstood what you were looking for, John. You just want to take the entire form as the modal, then collect the information in PHP?

Comment: @MetalFrog I want to be able to allow someone to fill out a second form and store that second form data into a hidden field in the parent form so then when the person submits the parent form I can easily parse the hidden values via php.

Comment: Serialization will be the way to go then. Hopefully I pushed you in the right direction.

Comment: @MetalFrog Yes initial testing shows this will work. Havent finished it yet but either way you helped me big time. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To capture the form into an input for posting:**

You want to [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form.

```
$('input').val( $('form').serialize() );
```

Then, in PHP, you just do a [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/parse_str) to split it back up into an array.

Also, keep in mind that there may be a better solution than passing field data around like this, but if you're hellbent on that implementation, this is probably the way to go.

**To open a form as a modal, then collect the data in PHP:**

```
// You can set this to not open by default and bind the opening to a button, or a link, etc...
$('form').dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

In PHP, your form will be contained within [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) as normal.

```
print_r( $_POST );
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use jQuery to create  fields like this:

```
$(".innerForm input").each(function() {
    $(".parentForm").append("<input type='hidden' name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"' value='"+$(this).val()+"'");
});
```

If you add the values to your page this way then you would just be able to access them as though they were normal parts of the $_POST

```
$_POST("hidden_field_name")
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated, and at this point you're doubling the size of the DOM too.

Comment: Very valid points, @MetalFrog; if your solution works for the OP then I would encourage them to serialize as you have shown. Yours is much more elegant but this approach still might be preferable or useful to someone.